# Getting error when renaming file in PHP

Tags: php

I am uploading a file using PHP to a folder in my directory and am unable to rename it using the following code

```
$da = date("dmY");

$ja = $uid.$da;

$mukesh = $app.$ja;

// If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors
if($err == '') {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile'][$mukesh], $uploadpath));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's PHP's official document about how to handle uploads: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

The method `move_uploaded_file()` requires two parameters, a filename of the temp file, and a new location.

```
$tmp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']; // temp path
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $uploadpath . '/' . $mukesh);
```

You will need to name your input element `userfile`.

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" />
```

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/Agri_Form_A.pdf/DS83479328032013): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\eg\sub.php on line 48

Comment: Make sure the folders exist and you have access to write.

Comment: ya there is folder and can access

Comment: Ah it appears your variable `$uploadpath` contains not only a directory, but a file name as well. Please review this variable. You can also just hardcode it: `move_uploaded_file($tmp, upload/' . $mukesh);` Also, don't forget to set an extension.

Comment: @mukhesh if this answer worked for you, press the big outlined V left of the answer so it turns green. This will allow people with a similar question to find the answer more easily and you will get answers faster on future questions!

Answer (score 0):

Based on code snippet provided, you can do following

```
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadpath);
```

When you upload a file, files will be store in upload location specified in php.ini using a temporary name. This file location with name can be accessed by $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you upload an image.if no error then

```
 $uploads_dir = 'as per you defined';

 $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];
 $name = 'custom_file_name.png';//$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
 move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir."/".$name);
```

Comment: so need to rename $name to $mukesh will it change the extension

Comment: you have to get the extension from the uploaded file logically and use  with the custom name you want for the uploaded file.

Comment: Some people use the $_FILES["file"]["type"] but it's not reliable as been given by the browser and not by PHP.

$userfile_extn = end(explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));

or

$userfile_extn = substr($_FILES['userfile']['name'], strrpos($_FILES['userfile']['name'], '.')+1);

or

$userfile_extn = explode(".", strtolower($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
$ext = array_pop($userfile_extn);

Answer (score 0):

You are renaming the temp name of file ...

When you want to rename the change the name with which you want to store the file

```
$filename = time().$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$upload_path = 'path_to_ur_upload_folder'.$filename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path );
```

first param in move_upload_file is temporary name that will be used by stream while copying an d uploading .. the second parameter is path where your file will be saved (along with file name).. it is the second parameter which will help you in renaming of file which is being uploaded